# How to get back the PostgreSQL database to a specific point in time?

Tags: postgresql, restore, recovery, write-ahead-logging

I was running a batch script in a PostgreSQL database which inserted values in different tables between 10:40 and 11:00. Later I came to know that the script was executed mistakenly. How can I get back my database to a state before 10:40 without stopping the server? I don't want the values which were inserted by batch during 10:40 to 11:00.

WAL has been configured.

I was struggling with this for the last three days. I have been trying with creating `recovery.conf` file with:

```
restore_command='path to my archivefile/%f %p'
recovery_target_time = '2014-10-15 10:40:00'
recovery_target_inclusive = true
```

Still I am not able to get my database backup to previous state.

Comment: Before you do anything else, make sure you're not deleting old WAL archives. Take a copy of your latest base backup and the WAL archives somewhere safe and read-only.

Comment: Did you configure WAL archiving *before* you had the problem? If you only configured it afterwards it will do you no good at all. What base backup are you starting the restore with? What message(s) appear in the logs when you start it, if any? Please explain in detail what you are doing, step by step.

Comment: "Without stopping the server"?

Comment: @jjanes i don't want my database to be shutdown.

Comment: @Craig Ringer I have configured the WAL before problem has occurred.Have taken the backup using pg_start_backup copied the data dir to diff location and pg_sop_backup.

Comment: @CraigRinger And my log looks like .
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2014-10-16 17:23:33 IST
LOG:  restored log file "0000000A.history" from archive
LOG:  starting point-in-time recovery to 2014-10-16 13:15:00+05:30
cp: cannot stat `/opt/test_wals/0000000A0000000000000011': No such file or directory
LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/11000080
LOG:  record with zero length at 0/11000080
LOG:  redo is not required
cp: cannot stat `/opt/test_wals/0000000B.history': No such file or directory
LOG: selected new timeline ID: 11
LOG: restored log file "0000000A.history" from archive

Comment: @user37651 Better to edit the question to add info. *Detailed* steps you took.

Comment: @user37651 You can't do a PITR recovery without stopping the database. In fact, you must stop it, *restore the base backup* and only *then* start it with an appropriate `recovery.conf`. PITR doesn't let you go backward in time, only forwards. So you have to restore an old enough backup, then replay forwards in time from it to reach the desired point.

Comment: Thank You Very Much @Craig it worked fine for me Now. And is there any other alternative for Point in time recovery. Like by using any SQL queries or any other tools can we achieve the same more easily.

Comment: @user37651 The manual sets out the options. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html

Answer (score 2):

If you know which rows were accidentally updated, you just don't know what the previous value of those rows were, then what you can do is:

1. Restore *to a new non-production server* from your base backup.
2. Recover that server to the point just before the error.
3. Write a query to select the values for the rows you know got mistakenly updated.
4. Turn that into a series of updates which can be run against the original production server.
5. Spin up yet another server which has been recovered up to current date to test those updates against to make sure they do the correct thing
6. Apply to production.

Of course if people or software have been relying on the bad values between when the error was made and now, then reversing the error will not reverse the decisions they made based on bad data.